# how to improve libraries methods feature?

Tags: android

I have used a library to display my items in mapView and view pager.

in this [library](https://github.com/nitrico/MapViewPager) there is only some places that is showing in viewPager but I want to get may current location that its code is:

```
@Override
  public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap map) {

    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
      android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
      != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.
      checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
      != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      return;
    }
```

and in `onMapReady()` that used in library there is not this features...and how is it possible to improve libraries method as I want.

Comment: Copy the source code of library to your code make your own library then improve it ?

Comment: cant i use library and do that?

Comment: dear  AhmetAcikalin  I have done what you said but now when i add my code to show my location,the map doesnt show my location maybe because the map viewpager is controling the camera and the items should add to viewpager adapter....how can i seprate this to see my place and the places together.